# Googleドライブ APIでのアップロード容量制限

Tags: api, google-drive-sdk

こんにちは。

GoogleドライブのAPIを利用して、ファイルのアップロードを検討しています。

GSuiteのサポートではAPIについて回答できなく、APIの制限についての
明確な取り決めがないらしいので、こちらに誘導されました。

識者の皆様はGoogleドライブAPIを利用して、３０GぐらいのZIPファイルを
アップロードした経験などはありますでしょうか？

４Gぐらいまでは確認できています。
また手動でのアップロードは問題ありませんでした。

Answer (score -1):

容量の問題でエラーとなったことはありません。
ただし、ファイル数が多いとLimitでエラーとなることは多々ありました。